# Not receiving WM_COMMAND in GetMessage loop

Tags: c++, winapi

Could someone explain why I never receive a `WM_COMMAND` message in my GetMessage loop?
I've checked and the WndProc is receiving the `WM_COMMAND` message, so i'm very confused why this doesn't work.

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) != 0)
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);

    if (msg.message == WM_COMMAND)
    {
        // This never happens:
        MessageBox(NULL, "WM_COMMAND", "WM_COMMAND", MB_OK);
    }
}
```

OS: Windows 8

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because WM_COMMAND is sent with SendMessage().  Which directly calls the window procedure.  Only messages posted with PostMessage() get added to the queue and are retrieved by GetMessage().

You can see this back in a utility like Spy++, it annotates messages that are posted with P and messages that are sent with S.