# GetMessage() loop doesn't get all windows messages?

Tags: c, winapi

I thought all windows messages were passed through the 'calling thread's message queue' and that all messages are passed through `GetMessage()` before being dispatched to the window?

But that doesn't seem to be the case. In my below code `GetMessage()` doesn't receive the main HWND's `WM_CREATE`, `WM_DESTROY` or `WM_CLOSE`. *How does this work?* Because the main HWND is receiving those messages, just not through the standard while loop.

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    // WM_CREATE, WM_DESTROY, WM_CLOSE messages dont get retrieved through GetMessage
    // ...but the window still received this message.
    switch (msg.message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        OutputDebugString(_T("WM_CREATE\n"));
    break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        OutputDebugString(_T("WM_DESTROY\n"));
        break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        OutputDebugString(_T("WM_CLOSE\n"));
        break;
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        OutputDebugString(_T("WM_LBUTTONDOWN\n"));
        break;
    default: {} break;
    }

    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

Theres a reason I'm interested in this, because I'd like to execute 'function callbacks' rather than subclass windows/chain window procedures/overwrite window procedures.

Ie;

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);

    int id = (int)GetProp(msg.hwnd, "PROP_ID");
    int translatedMsg = translateMessage(id, msg.message);

    // but with this technique I miss WM_CREATE, WM_DESTROY, WM_CLOSE
    evtCallbacks[translatedMsg](hinstance, msg.hwnd, msg.wParam, msg.lParam);

    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not receiving WM\_COMMAND in GetMessage loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099527/not-receiving-wm-command-in-getmessage-loop), also [How to intercept a message: “WM_QUIT || WM_DESTROY || WM_CLOSE” WinAPI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827617/how-to-intercept-a-message-wm-quit-wm-destroy-wm-close-winapi/18828222#18828222).

Comment: I assume you have a good reason for fighting the operating system, instead of working with it? Subclassing is the standard and recommended way to modify the behavior of a window.